# Could someone help show how to this simple Hasse diagram using tikz package?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I am trying to use tikz package to draw this Hasse program, but there are so many examples online, and I don't know how to follow. Could someone show me how to draw this simple Hasse program? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Questions should include a short compilable example starting `\documentclass{}` and ending `\end{document}`. Right now, your question is liable to get closed as lacking details and clarity. (I wouldn't vote to close it yet myself as you're a new contributor, but that's the pattern.) If you're trying to use `tikz`, what's the problem? Have you looked at the tutorials in the manual? Searched for similar diagrams?

Comment: a start for you `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (y) node[left]{$y$}  
(4,1) coordinate (x) node[right]{$x$}  
(3,3) coordinate (u) node[above]{$u$}  
;
\draw (y)--(x)--(u)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
`

Comment: As you say, there are a lot of examples online. Why don't you just choose one and start with that? It is always better and more efficient to show what you tried already, because there are always different approaches to drawing with Ti*k*Z.